# Testng fails to record test failures

Tags: selenium-webdriver, frameworks, testng, listener, testng.xml

I have used testng to run the testcases. ITestResult listener is used to capture the test status and it is given in after method. Pls help why testng is not recording test failures?

Comment: please provide more details. What exactly you are using, any error, code being used etc. to debug.

Comment: ITestResult collect test failures. Maybe this thread can help you find out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68601316/how-to-get-failed-tests-details-in-selenium-using-ireporter/68605608#68605608

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take screenshots of failed tests, the following code may help you.

1. you must configure the listener in your xml test suite

   ```
   <listeners>
       <listener class-name="package.your.listener.ScreenshotListener" />
   </listeners>
   ```
2. implement your listener

   public class ScreenshotListener extends TestListenerAdapter {

   ```
   @Override
   public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {
       super.onTestFailure(result);

       if (!result.isSuccess()) {

           WebDriver driver = getDriverByResult(result);
           String methodName = result.getName();

           try {

               File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
               String reportDirectory = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")).getAbsolutePath() + "/target/surefire-reports";
               File destFile = new File(reportDirectory + "/failure_screenshots/"
                       + buildFileNameByMethod(methodName)+ ".png");

               FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, destFile);
               Reporter.log("<a href='" + destFile.getAbsolutePath() + "'> <img src='" + destFile.getAbsolutePath() + "' height='100' width='100'/> </a>");
           } catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }
   }
   ```